# Synchronous and async methods in a web.api

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

Can someone please explain if this code is a potential deadlock.
Mixing sync database calls with async database calls like the code below. Or if the async call was executed first, is that the risk for deadlock.

```
    [Route("{id}/someobjects")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<SomobjectDto>))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetSomeobjects(string id)
    {
        var syncMethodResult = SyncDBCallMethod(); //In this method there is a databas call..

        var asyncMethodresult = await AsyncDBMCallMethod(1L);  //In this method there is a Async databas call..
```

Comment: the async call wont start till the synchronous one finishes in this case. Once you are not mixing blocking calls like `Result` or `.Wait` with async, you should be able to have async and sync calls. Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: Look seriously into whether `SyncDBCallMethod` can be converted. You get the most benefit if you can make *all* long running activities (and DB calls are always assumed to be so) as some form of async.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the async `AsyncDBMCallMethod` call wont start till the synchronous `SyncDBCallMethod` finishes.

Once you are not mixing blocking calls like `Result` or `.Wait` in async/await functions, and properly *await* async functions, you should be able to have async and sync calls together.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: ok. thank you. but the sync method will block the threed? so is it any meaning/benefit of doing this semi async over just a normal synchronous way?